# Fluent NHibernate and mapping IList<int>

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

```
public class Template
{
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<int> DocIds { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateMap : ClassMap<Template>
{
    public TemplateMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);

        WithTable("Template");
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<string>("TemplateID ").SubClass<Template>("not null", m => { });
    }
}
```

There are two tables: Template and TemplateDocument.  They are as follows:

```
Template
-------------------------
TemplateID int
Name varchar(255)

TemplateDocument
-------------------------
TemplateID int
DocID int
```

I would like to just return the Template object filled with the DocIDs from the TemplateDocument table for each template (by TemplateID).  Is that possible?  How do I go about setting up the mapping for this?  It seems so simple, yet I can't seem to get this mapping to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have `TemplateDocument` mapped?

Comment: If you really want to map a list of ints, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942001/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-of-liststring/1949495#1949495

Comment: Yes, I meant to enter `ClassMap<Template>`.  But thanks for putting me on the right path, dotjoe.  I was able to get what I wanted by
doing the following:

`HasMany(x => x.DocIds).WithKeyColumn("TemplateId").WithTableName("TemplateDocument").AsElement("DocID");`

Comment: Wow, be careful if you are also mapping the TemplateDocument. If you manipulate the `DocIds` property it is possible you will blow up any TemplateDocuments as you'll effectively be changing their ids.