# Mapping a collection to a subselect with Fluent nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've got a class that looks like:

```
public class Competitor
{
    public virtual int CompetitorId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> SportsCompeted { get; set; }
}
```

`SportsCompeted` is a list of SportIDs (strings) resolved like so:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT SportID FROM results WHERE competitorId = xxx
```

How would I go about mapping something like that?
Looking at HasMany I can specify a `Where` clause, but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for in this case?

I'm using Fluent Mappings, omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a View in SQL to basically do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SportID, CompetitorID FROM results
```

Then, in my mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x.CompetitorDisciplines)
    .Not.LazyLoad()
    .Inverse()
    .AsBag()
    .KeyColumn("competitorId")
    .Element("DisciplineCode")
    .Table("vCompetitorDisciplines");
```

That seemed to produce the desired result.
Slow, but it's only a one time (or once per day) operation....

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to this with `.Element()`. Something like:

```
HasMany(x => x.SportsCompeted)
    .KeyColumn("CompetitorId")
    .Element("SportID") // You can define element type as second parameter
    .Table("results");
```

More info:
[Mapping collection of strings with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606607/mapping-collection-of-strings-with-nhibernate)
[Fluent NHIbernate automapping of List<string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942001/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-of-liststring)

---

**Edit:**

Let's say that you have your `Result` and `Sport` entities instead:

```
public class Sport
{
    public virtual int SportId { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Result : Entity
{
    public virtual ResultId { get; set; }
    public virtual Competitor Competitor { get; set; }
    public virtual Sport Sport { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Competitor
{
    public virtual int CompetitorId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Result> Results { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

Your `HasMany` would now look like this:

```
// For this, you would need to have Result and Sport classes mapped
// This property isn't necessary for your Sports Competed query
HasMany(x => x.Results)
    .KeyColumn("CompetitorId")
    .Table("results");
```

Then you could use ie. Linq to get the results you want:

```
var sports = session.Query<Result>()
    .Where(x => x.Competitor.CompetitorId = competitorId)
    .Select(x => x.Sport) // Or .Select(x => x.Sport.SportId)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: but that doesn't take into account the DISTINCT part does it? or am i reading this wrong...? My results table has many SportID for the same CompetitorID

Comment: Sorry, I failed to see `DISTINCT` clause there. You're right about `Where` not being helpful in your case. Instead of doing this within mapping, I would rather have a separate query (HQL, Criteria, QueryOver or LINQ) in a data layer that will get a list of sports competed ids by `CompetitorId`.

Comment: Sounds good... have you got any example of how to do this with Fluent?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully, it will give you a starting point to think about.

Comment: Is there anyway to lazy-load this?

Comment: The last expression is just a query you would be calling when necessary. The `Competitor.Results` property, although not used in this query, should be lazy loaded by default.

Comment: hmm- i can't go changing the model though- this is being extracted from SQL, and then stored in a nosql store for querying...
so trying to do my HasMany as a lazy-loaded query i think?