# Fluent NHibernate mapping for IList<int>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate 2.0.3 with NHibernate 4.0.0.4000
Backend DB is Sqlite.

My entity and mapping is defined as this:

```
public class PriceHistory
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<long> Date { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<float> Price { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<int> Volume { get; set; }
    public virtual float MinPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual float MaxPrice { get; set; }
}

class PriceHistoryMap : ClassMap<PriceHistory>
{
    public PriceHistoryMap()
    {
        Table("PriceHistories");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        HasMany<long>(x => x.Date);
        HasMany<float>(x => x.Price);
        HasMany<int>(x => x.Volume);
        Map(x => x.MinPrice);
        Map(x => x.MaxPrice);
    }   
}
```

When I try to start the application I get this exception:

```
Association references unmapped class: System.Int64
```

It doesn't matter if I have int, long or float. I always get an exception, as if I have to define the mapping for every basic value type.

Whats wrong here? Whats the correct mapping for Lists of value types?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might have to have it as `HasMany<int>(x => x.Volume).Element("Value");`

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942001/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-of-liststring/1949495#1949495) might also help with your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but it sounds like your floats, ints, and longs live in a different table?

If that's the case, you may have to set up a `HasMany` relationship for each, like so:

```
HasMany<int>(x => x.Volume)
    .Table("PriceHistoryVolumes")
    .KeyColumn("PriceHistoryID")
    .Element("Volume");
```