# Mapping value-type collection in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

Similar question: [Mapping collection of strings with Entity Framework or Linq to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161702/mapping-collection-of-strings-with-entity-framework-or-linq-to-sql)

I have a role class:

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

I have a mapping table in the db, "RoleActionMapping" with the columns, "RoleID" and "Action".  "RoleID" is a foreign key point to the Role table, and "Action" is a varchar.  I cannot seem to setup my EF mapping to populate the Role class with the RoleActions.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF doesn't offer such mapping.

If you want to map it you must use:

```
public class Role
{
  public int RoleID { get; set;}
  public virtual IList<RoleAction> Actions { get; set; } // you should initialize collection
}

public class RoleAction
{
  public int ActionId { get; set; } // PK must be defined or entity is readonly
  public string Action { get; set; }
  public virtual Role { get; set; }
}
```

You can further extend `Role` class to provied not mapped property returning `IEnumerable<string>` which will internally select data from `Actions` property.

But once you follow this approach you should consider model it as M:N relation between `Role` and `Action` entity.

Comment: Too bad, I wish it did.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @manu08 For a perspective on *why* "collections of value objects" might not be offered, see http://mhinze.com/2009/01/10/there-is-never-a-collection-of-value-objects/ (This is in general Domain Driven Design terms, not Entity Framework specific).